# Facebook SDK Android 3.6.0 error on login

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I tried to do everything I found on Google with

> Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur
>   if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.

above of all StackOverflow's posts and none was OK for me.

I'm using `FragmentActivity`on my app, and I call the `LoginButton` from my `TesseraFragment` (Fragment) and I implement `onSessionStateChange` on my parent activity, `HomeActivity` which, as I said, `extends FragmentActivity`. **I USE TABHOST**

When I try to login for the **first time**, it is okay, even when I cancel the request and I try again, it's everything OK.

The problem comes when I close my app, and I reopen (without being in background) and try to login. On my logcat I can see:

```
// LOGGER FROM on onSessionStateChange
05-19 18:27:22.956: V/dbg(23838): state: OPENING
05-19 18:27:22.956: V/dbg(23838): session: {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:749814685063953}
05-19 18:27:22.956: V/dbg(23838): exception: null
//
05-19 18:27:22.956: W/ApplicationPackageManager(23838): getCSCPackageItemText()
05-19 18:27:22.986: E/com.facebook.LoginActivity(23838): Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
```

I overrided `onActivityResult` on `HomeActivity` even closing all sessions but didn't work:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        System.out.println("ouh yeah");
    }
    if (hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab)
            .get(hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() - 1)
            .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

also tried to be overriden on my Fragment but nothing happened.

**My AndroidManifest.xml doesn't has launchMode** and I'm using Facebook SDK 3.6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing [setting the button to the Fragment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0):

`authButton.setFragment(this);`